# ideas to display and edit source code in an AJAX application

Tags: ajax, web-applications

i'm looking for ways to display and edit source code (ala google docs) in a web application (AJAX). any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Bespin from Mozilla](https://bespin.mozilla.com/)